# How to hide unwanted measures

Tags: definition, cube, activepivot, measures

AP 4.4.3, APL 2.7.0

Hi,

When defining a post-processed measure we end up with two measures available to us in Active Pivot Live.  E.g. the definition below will give us the measures "Yield Curve.SUM" and "Yield Curve.TenorDetail".  As we've got a lot of measures like this, we end up with a lot of useless SUM measures cluttering up the interface.

So, since we only need "Yield Curve.TenorDetail", can we somehow hide "Yield Curve.SUM"?

```
<measure name="Yield Curve" aggregationFunctions="SUM" >
        <postProcessor pluginKey="TenorDetail" >
            <properties>
                <entry key="id" value="TenorDetail" />
                <entry key="vectorMeasure" value="Yield Curve.SUM" />
                <entry key="analysisDimensionName" value="Tenor" />             
            </properties>
        </postProcessor>
    </measure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by defining subcube properties in the shared context of your cube definition and explicitely list all the measures that you want to be available for the users

For instance the definition below will only show Yield Curve.TenorDetail and no other measure:

```
    <sharedContexts>
       <subCubeProperties isAccessGranted="true">
          <grantedMeasures>
             <measure>Yield Curve.TenorDetail</measure>
          </grantedMeasures>
        </subCubeProperties>
    </sharedContexts>
```

Comment: Thanks - that does the trick.  Are there any plans to have a mechanism to allow everything, but deny certain measures?  Using <grantedMeasures> on a large cube seems a very verbose way of hiding a few measure.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no such plan. What can appear to be very verbose in some cases can be the opposite in some other cases. For instance if you have multiple chained post-processors but want to display only the last measure of your chain